# jQuery resizing rotated elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, rotation

I've searched around for this problem but haven't really found a definitive solution or example to follow to resolve it.  Using jQuery, when I rotate a resizable, the handles and subsequent resizing operations are goofed up.  How can I resolve or work around this?  Here's an example of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/LVU7c/

The code in the fiddle is:

```
$('#widget').resizable({ handles: 'n, e, s, w' });
```

and CSS to rotate a simple div tag 90 degrees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic concept for this was posted by [Linus Gudn Jokela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1693931/linus-gudn-jokela), who deleted his answer, and has not restored it despite my request.

You could use an rotated inner wrapper for your content, then attach the resizing handles to the outer element, which remains unrotated.

Some JS code will be needed to keep the content in sync with the container as far as height and width are concerned. Here is a complete demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/fXthv/

**JS:**

```
$('#widget').resizable({
    handles: 'n, e, s, w',
    resize: function(){
        correct(this);
    }
});

function correct(el) {
    var widget = $('#widget_content'),
        deg = widget.data("rotate");
    if (typeof deg == "number") {
        widget.css({
            width: (function () {
                if (deg % 180 == 0) return $(el).outerWidth()
                else return $(el).outerHeight()
            })(),
            height: (function () {
                if (deg % 180 == 0) return $(el).outerHeight()
                else return $(el).outerWidth()
            })(),
            marginLeft: (function () {
                if (deg % 360 == 90) return $(el).outerWidth();
                else if (deg % 360 == 180) return $(el).outerWidth();
                else return 0;
                //else if (deg % 360 == 270) return $(el).outerWidth();
            })(),
            marginTop: (function () {
                if (deg % 360 == 270) return $(el).outerHeight();
                else if (deg % 360 == 180) return $(el).outerHeight();
                else return 0;
                //else if (deg % 360 == 270) return $(el).outerWidth();
            })()
        });
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#widget {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #cecece;
}
#widget_content {
    margin-left:100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/2106003206.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    /* removing the styles below will make the image appear as expected */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    /* Opera */
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="widget">
    <div id="widget_content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a pretty nifty solution. A tiny bug with it is that whenever you resize the div, it jumps just a little bit up and left unless it is up against its parent element's edge. You can see this if you shrink the div on its top/left side, and then resize from any side.

Comment: @ajp15243 What browser are you trying this in? I can't seem to replicate it in FF (although maybe I'm just misunderstanding how to reproduce the problem)

Comment: Should be latest stable Chrome (v25.0.1364.97). I am also on Linux, and I occasionally see small odd layout problems that I suspect are because of Gnome3, but I don't typically see it on jsFiddle. To better explain reproducing it, grab the top handle and drag down, then grab the left handle and drag right. Then, without dragging too much, grab and slightly move the right or bottom handle while watching the position of the box (easiest to see if you look at the top-left corner).

Comment: I am not seeing it in FF19. Interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  How would I make the inner content stretch to fill the parent still though?  For example, rotating an arrow image at 90 degree intervals.  Here's a fiddle of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/eC3ZK/

Comment: @chinabuffet You would have to use jQuery to flip the width and height of the rotated element with the parent. Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/GN9AR/

Comment: Would I do that for just the 90/270 rotations though?  This fiddle shows the rotation a little more dynamically (click to rotate incrementally).  http://jsfiddle.net/Lb7GL/  What would I have to change?  Also, what's the margin-left for?  Is that necessary because of the origin transforms to 0,0?  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @chinabuffet Here is a demonstration with dynamic rotation: http://jsfiddle.net/z3YTw/

Comment: Does that work for 180/270 degrees for you (2nd/3rd clicks)?  The arrow disappears for me.

Comment: @chinabuffet Whoops, guess I didn't save the last changes I made. Give me a second.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot what are you trying to show in that fiddle, the original problem?

Comment: @chinabuffet nope. it was something like the solution given. the content is put inside a div in and rotated. make its width/height same as wrapper and use resizable on wrapper div.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Is the inner image supposed to scale correctly still though?  In that fiddle, when I resize the outer div horizontally, the image grows vertically instead (using Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :)
It works for me, except that you need to wotk som with the positioning of the content inside of your widget.

http://tinyurl.com/jsfiddleee